# Framework7 setting time in a form

Tags: html-framework-7, phonegap

Is there anyway to set just the time using Framework7 instead of using the Date-Time in a form?

Regards,

Quelma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This will work with framework7 also

```
<input type="time" name="time1">
```

**Note: type="time" is not supported in Firefox, or Internet Explorer 12 and earlier versions**.

[Time Input in HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time)

Comment: Thanks @rashidnk!

Comment: welcome @Quelms, if my answer helped you,please vote up and accept the answer, thnks

Comment: Hi @rashidn, I need a score of 15 on reputation to vote up, that is why it does not show. But it is recorded already.